# Where are contacts located on Xperia P internal storage?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery, sony-xperia-p

I have SE xperia P, and it stopped working, or at least the display did. I can access the internal memory (where I've been saving all contacts, which i didn't back up), is it possible to find and extract them? If so, how.
[image]

These file I see when i connect the phone to PC, but I have no idea where to find contacts or SMS/MMS and such.

Comment: There is nothing when i search for %contact%, when i search for %data% and %.db% i dont get any good search results as well

Comment: If you go manually into /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts what do you get? Do you have root, are you using a root explorer, do you have read access to the `/data` folder?

Comment: this is the only data folder I can see/have access to http://imgur.com/OE4RWh1

Comment: `/Android/Data/` is not the same as `/Data` the latter is in the `/` folder, otherwise known as the [tag:root] folder, so I guess without root you cannot access the database. There are code ways to access it, that would be an app with the "Read or Write Contacts Data" permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a phone with [root](/questions/tagged/root) access. The folder that *usually* stores the contacts is `data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db` As  you would imagine they are placed in a 'safer' part of the device storage.

However, the `/data` folder is accessed via root directory `/`

You can root the device or you can use a [Contacts Contract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) to access the database programatically, but as a normal user you can't.

As noted in the comments `/android/data` is not the same as `/data`